# Cassandra 1.2.x - RAM heap and JRE parameter - questions for better understanding

Tags: cassandra

May I ask some questions, to get a better understand of Cassandra and JRE and RAM configuration (referring to V1.2.5 and documentation of May 2013):
The current documentation and lots of google research still left some open questions to me.

Interested in using it as simple embedded datastore for a few hundred GB of data on 6 machines distributed in 3 locations, that also run a java application.

1) Cassandra's stack sizing

The Windows .bat file has a default set to 1GB, which I think is a bug, the Linux cassandra-env.sh defines 180k. Is this a "just leave it with 180k, fire and forget about stack size" thing?

2) Cassandra's RAM usage

When using JNA, system RAM is basically split into 3 main areas:

1. Cassandra uses the assigned Java heap
2. Cassandra uses exra RAM obtained by JNA
3. Operation system uses leftovers of RAM as disk cache

Current documentation basically only recommends: "don't set Java heap size higher than 8GB"

- Is this info still up to date? (It could be that this statement was from a time, when CMS Garbage collector wasn't included in Java 1.6)
- How do I limit the JNA heap (is it the 'row_cache_size_in_mb' parameter?)
- what is a good layout rule of thumb for the 3 RAM areas (Java HEAP, JNA extra HEAP, OS CACHE) on a dedicated system in Cassandra 1.2.x ?

  - when having lots of RAM (128GB)?
  - when having few RAM (4GB)?

(I know about the heap size calculator, this question is more for theoretical understanding and up to date info)

3) Java Runtime

Why is the recommendation still to use Java 1.6 and not Java 1.7.

- Is this a "maturity" operational recommendation?
- Are there specific problems known from the near past?
- Or just waiting a bit more until more people report flawless operation with 1.7?

4) Embedding Cassandra

The "-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1" in the C* start scripts is a slight hint to separate Cassandra from application code, which usually lives better with higher threshold. On the other hand the "1"  might also be a bit outdated -
Is this setting still that important? (since now using CMS Garbage collector and JNA-RAM and maybe even using Java1.7?)

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you looking at Xmx?  I don't see Xss at all in cassandra.bat

2) Mostly correct.  Cassandra doesn't actually require JNA for off-heap allocation for a long time now (1.0 IIRC).

You don't want heap larger than 8GB because CMS and G1 still choke and cause STW pauses eventually.  Short explanation: fragmentation.  Longer: http://www.scribd.com/doc/37127094/GCTuningPresentationFISL10

Cassandra does off-heap allocation for row cache and for storage engine metadata.  The former is straightforward to tune; the latter is not.  Basically, you need to have about 20GB of ram per TB of compressed data, end of story.  Things you can do to reduce memory usage include disabling compression, reducing bloom filter accuracy, and increasing index_interval.  All of which are going to reduce your performance, other things being equal.

3) Maturity.  We're late adopters; we have less problems that way.  Cassandra 2.0 will require Java7.

4) This is not outdated.

Comment: Thank you
 
And sorry my first question, i really messed up Xss and Xmx. Shame on me.

Your answer made me do some more googling, I found your presentation about 1.2/2.0, in case someone else stumbles over my stackoverflow question, the presentation also contains info about memory and about V2.0: http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/nyc-jonathan-ellis-keynote-cassandra-12-20